# How to prevent multiple login for a jwt token based authentication in django rest-framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

https://dev.to/fleepgeek/prevent-multiple-sessions-for-a-user-in-your-django-application-13oo
i have followed the above article for achieving preventing multiple login. But the above process is not working and it does not through any errors.

What i have done to test after copying above code>

- I have loged in with user credentials in postman. I have collected
  the jwt token which is a response.
- I have stored the first jwt token in notepad.
- next i have loged again.
- Now i have used old jwt token ( i mean first token) to get some data
  and i am able to access it. What i am expecting here is. I don't want
  first token to be working anymore.

Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not use sessions? Sessions get this done. The post you mentioned is using sessions. You are using tokens. There is a difference. The thing is, the token IS you, people can use this token from any device to access your data. Keep it safe, and set a refresh-time for the token.

Comment: Thanks for your advice @nigel239. I will try with sessions.

Comment: You need to allow the token goes to the blacklist after it is expired. Then you need to use the refresh token to maintain the authentication.

Comment: @EliasPrado Yeah I have followed this method. It worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your signals are not working. Try to include the following line in your `__init__.py` file under the `accounts` app.

```
default_app_config = 'accounts.apps.AccountsConfig'
```

Comment: He wasn't even using sessions. Ofcourse the signals don't get sent.